# Flutter: Search inside the List

Tags: flutter

I am trying to using the `mobile_number` plugin. Basically, I am fetching the SimCard number.

Here is the code.

```
   String _mobileNumber = '';
  List<SimCard> _simCard = <SimCard>[];
    Future<void> initMobileNumberState() async {
        if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
          await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
          return;
        }
        String mobileNumber = '';
        // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
        try {
          mobileNumber = await MobileNumber.mobileNumber;
          _simCard = await MobileNumber.getSimCards;
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          debugPrint("Failed to get mobile number because of '${e.message}'");
        }
    
        // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
        // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
        // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
        if (!mounted) return;
    
        setState(() {
          _mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        });
      }
    
      Widget fillCards() {
        List<Widget> widgets = _simCard
            .map((SimCard sim) => Text(
                'Sim Card Number: (${sim.countryPhonePrefix}) - ${sim.number}\nCarrier Name: ${sim.carrierName}\nCountry Iso: ${sim.countryIso}\nDisplay Name: ${sim.displayName}\nSim Slot Index: ${sim.slotIndex}\n\n'))
            .toList();
        return Column(children: widgets);
      }
```

This is working fine I can see the mobile number.

But now I need to search the number inside the list.

I checked some of the questions on SO to get it done but I am not good with lists.
I tried using some of the examples and comes up with below. But this is incorrect with so many errors.

```
var comparenumber =  _simCard.map((SimCard sim).where((sim.number) => sim.number.toLowerCase().contains(mobile.toLowerCase()).toList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search if the list has a number or part of a number (say the result would be `true` searching for `641` in a list that has a number `641-819-xxxx`)

you can use this code

```dart
bool searchNumber(String number) {
  return _simCard.where((element) => element.number.contains(number)).isNotEmpty;
}
```

if you want to search for an exact number match replace `element.number.contains(number)` with `element.number == number` as in dart `==` for strings compare the string value, not pointers as in Java for example.

So, what is `where`?

`where` is a function in the abstract class `Iterable` (and lists in dart are iterable) that take a predicate or a test function and returns an iterable that has only elements that match the predicate.

returned iterable can be collected to a list or you can use some other functions or properties directly on it like `isNotEmpty` in our case

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try. +1

Comment: @Rocx let me know and I can edit the question if needed

Comment: Do i need to change element with other values.

Comment: @Rocx element is a name of a variable of the same type as the element of the list, it can be renamed and it's equal to `where((SimCard s)=>s.number==number)`

Comment: @Rocx here you go :+1: